# Почему функция putchar() работает странно?

Tags: c

Изчуаю С, столкнулся с проблемами с getchar() и putchar()

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        putchar(c);

    }
}
```

Здесь код работает нормально:

```
hello world
hello world
```

Но если я хочу узнать, какой значнение принимает **(c = getchar()) != EOF**, то у меня возникают проблемы. Выводится не строка, а поочередно буквы.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c,b;
    /* printf(EOF); Segmentation fault (Core dumped) */
    while (b = ((c = getchar()) != EOF)){
        printf("Bool: %d\n", b);
        putchar(c);

    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
hello world
Bool: 1
h
Bool: 1
e
Bool: 1
l
Bool: 1
l
Bool: 1
o
Bool: 1

Bool: 1
w
Bool: 1
o
Bool: 1
r
Bool: 1
l
Bool: 1
d
Bool: 1
```

Как это работает? И почему я не могу вывести константу **EOF**?

Comment: Что-то я вопрос не понимаю. *"Выводится не строка, а поочередно буквы"* Ну, вы же сами вставили printf. Уберите, и символы пойдут подряд.

Comment: `EOF` это константа `-1`. `printf` в качестве первого параметра ожидает строку, то есть, фактически, адрес первого символа строки. Адрес `-1` некорректный, вот и ошибка.

Comment: аа. он поочередно что-ли вводит и  выводит символы? В консоли пытаюсь вывести.

Comment: @AminevTimur getchar, printf, putchar, затем снова getchar, printf, putchar.

Comment: *"EOF это константа -1"* На большинстве компиляторов, но стандартом не гарантируется.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat но ведь если б так было   getchar, printf, putchar, затем снова getchar, printf, putchar, то я бы набирал строку -> printf -> выводит первый символ -> ввод строки -> printf -> выводит первый символ

Comment: @MarkShevchenko Как сделать так, чтобы сначала выводился b,а потом все остальные симовлы из c? к примеру, `Bool:1 hello world`?

Comment: @AminevTimur Просто getchar так работает. Если вы ее вызвали и ввели больше одного символа, то следующие вызовы, вместо того, чтобы останавливать программу и ждать ввода, будут возвращать следующий символ из строки, которую вы ввели раньше. Так происходит, пока символы в строке не закончатся.

Comment: И не такое там выводится - нет там переводов строк перед `Bool`.

Comment: `char c; while ((c = getchar()) != '\0') { putchar(c);  }  putchar('\n');` -  это все :)